# ReferenceError: Stage is not defined (Javascript in Laravel 4)

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to create a simple variable in javascript, by echoing out something from a database in Laravel 4.

```
var artist_name = {{$artist->stage_name}};
```

When I look at the source, the echo is working (it displays the stage name fine).

But my javascript isn't working, and I get the error:

```
ReferenceError: Stage is not defined
```

where "Stage" is the output from the echo.

Do you have any idea why it is complaining about this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote the string "Stage":

```
var artist_name = "{{$artist->stage_name}}";

// or 
var artist_name = \"{{$artist->stage_name}}\";
```

depending on how you generate this output. Otherwise, JS is looking for a variable named `Stage`.

If `Stage` is actually a (JS) variable then it shouldn't be quoted, but just isn't available at the time this code runs.